# (command) if x==list in stata

Tags: if-statement, stata

I want to be able to write an `if` expression without having to resort to a large number of or "|" operators. For example:

```
drop if x==1 | x==3 | x==5 | x==7
```

Is there a simpler way to write this ie:

```
drop if x==one of (1,3,5,7)
```

I realize a for loop will work but that isn't a very tidy solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `inlist` for that

```
sysuse auto



    tab  rep78

     Repair |
Record 1978 |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
          1 |          2        2.90        2.90
          2 |          8       11.59       14.49
          3 |         30       43.48       57.97
          4 |         18       26.09       84.06
          5 |         11       15.94      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |         69      100.00
keep if inlist(rep78,1,2,3)

 tab  rep78

     Repair |
Record 1978 |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
          1 |          2        5.00        5.00
          2 |          8       20.00       25.00
          3 |         30       75.00      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |         40      100.00
```